# took date from dropdownlist and filter table by ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Guys have a little problem with ajax.I have 2 actions on view

```
<body>
    @Html.Action("SetSearchFilter")
    @Html.Action("FillTable")
</body>
```

First Action is a DropDownList

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Manager, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownList("SearchingManagerId", new SelectList(Model.Managers, "UserId", "PrettyFullName",
        Model.SelectedValueManager),
        string.Empty, new { style = "width: 200px" })
```

Second is a Table formed by

```
 public PartialViewResult FillTable(int year, int? ManagerId)
        {
            int currentUserId = (int)Session["CurrentUserId"];
            return PartialView("_QualificationTable", planService.GetQualificationViewModel(year.ToString(), currentUserId,ManagerId));
        }
```

How i can filtering by ajax,get data from dropdownlist and took it to table?I think i should use smth like this

```
  $("#DropDownListId").on("change", function () {
                    var valueForSearch = //How i can get?;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("FillQualificationTable")',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        async: false,
                        data: { year: currentYear, ManagerId: valueForSearch },
                        beforeSend: showSpinner,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#tableid').html(data);
                        },
                        complete: hideSpinner,
                    });
```

I working with ajax first time,so have some problems =(
values in DDList looks like this

```
<select id="SearchingManagerId" name="SearchingManagerId" style="width: 200px"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">user1</option>
<option value="5">user2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jquery "this"](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$("#DropDownListId").on("change", function () {
                    var valueForSearch = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("FillQualificationTable")',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        async: false,
                        data: { year: currentYear, ManagerId: valueForSearch },
                        beforeSend: showSpinner,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#tableid').html(data);
                        },
                        complete: hideSpinner,
                    });
```

---

[Look example](http://jsfiddle.net/xcx1phh3/)